# .htaccess - how to tell wordpress to ignore a directory

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

My wordpress website has seo friendly urls like `http://mysite.com/mywebpage` .  I installed wordpress in my `/var/www` directory.

However, on my server, I also have a directory called `/var/www/mywebpage` because that directory holds files like `/var/www/mywebpage/product1.jpg`, `/var/www/mywebpage/product2.jpg` etc...

Now everytime I go to `http://mysite.com/mywebpage`, the browser gives me a 403 Forbidden error because if a directory with the same name as a wordpress page exists, then the directory takes precedence.  I have a few more web directories that suffer from this problem.

How do i edit my .htaccess file such that a wordpress page takes precedence over the following three directories: `/var/www/mywebpage`, `/var/www/myproductpage` and `/var/www/mygraphics`.

However, if someone goes to `http://mysite.com/mywebpage/product1.jpg`, i want them to be able to see the physical image file.

Here's my current .htaccess from Wordpress.

```
# WORDPRESS Rules below, DO NOT EDIT!
#uploaded files
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?files/$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*wp-content/plugins.*
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?files/(.*) wp-content/blogs.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/wp-admin$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-.*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

<IfModule mod_security.c>
<Files async-upload.php>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer (and more maintainable in the long run, without getting into more `mod_rewrite` or `mod_alias` black magic) is really to not name the directories the same as your seo-friendly-links. Use something like `mywebpage_images`, `myproductpage_images`, etc. for these directories.

Comment: I agree, putting them into an images directory is probably your best bet.

Comment: yes, i agree, but this is part of a legacy issue and I have to preserve these directories and the web page